# Конструкция jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет. Что означает след. конструкция jquery?:

```
(function($){

})(jQuery);
```

Спасибо.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/222174/javascript-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 2):

Лямбда-функция с параметром "$" вызывается сразу же. В качестве параметра $ передается объект jQuery.

Вот, в качестве примера:

```
(function($){
    alert($);
})(5);
```

**Результат** - *диалоговое окно с текстом "5"*

Comment: Ну вы хоть расшифровывайте, что такое "лямбда-функция") Не каждый знает смысл.

Comment: Вы-то точно должны знать :)

Comment: @0xFFh да речь не про меня)

Answer (score 2):

Она описывает объявление анонимной самовызывающейся функции, которая сразу же выполнится с параметром jQuery. Это делается для того чтобы избежать конфликтов с другими библиотеками, который используют символ '$' в работе.